# Cannot use a scalar value as an array - array push

Tags: php

this is my code.

```
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $m &= is_object($emp) ? $emp->mobile_no : $emp['mobile_no'];
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $m [] = $row->mobile_no;
    }
```

it warns that Cannot use a scalar value as an array. my simple solution is this

```
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        if (is_object($emp)) {
            $emp->mobile_no[] = $row->mobile_no;
        } else {
            $emp['mobile_no'][] = $row->mobile_no;
        }
    }
```

but now in every loop it do some same things. what can i do? 
this is what i am expecting to create.

```
contacts: {
address: "329/A",
corresponding_address: "Negambo",
mobile_no: [
"0719896992",
"0713345582"
],
telephone_no: [
"0915717472",
"0915715094"
]
}
```

////////////////////////////////update

ok i fixed by this way

```
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $tel = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $tel[] = $row->telephone_no;
    }
    if (is_object($emp)) {
        $emp->telephone_no = $tel;
    } else {
        $emp['telephone_no'] = $tel;
    }
```

Comment: $m[] - is not an array this is your root issue.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use `$m` in the correct way

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$m = array();
$m[] = is_object($emp) ? $emp->mobile_no : $emp['mobile_no'];
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $m [] = $row->mobile_no;
}
```

Of course I say this with no knowledge of what `$emp` is.  I am assuming here that it is at least equivalent to `$row` as they sure this property `$row->mobile_no`.